# Azure RBAC: REST API returns empty response for unauthorized request

Tags: azure

Through experimentation with the Azure REST API, I have found cases in which a response for an unauthorized request has a 200 code with an empty response:

```
{
    "value": []
}
```

Specifically, I've observed two scenarios, both occurring using a client application authenticated with a valid bearer token:

1. If the client has no roles assigned, requests to any API requiring explicit access return a 403 error code as expected.
2. If the client has a role assigned that does not authorize the endpoint being accessed, a 200 response with an empty payload is returned.

Regarding the second scenario, I would expect that this request would still return a 403 error code since the access is unauthorized given  that the assigned role(s).

Is this expected behavior?

---

Concretely, I've tested the second scenario above by assigning the [Network Contributor role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#network-contributor) to an application and attempting various GET operations outside of the actions permitted. For all unauthorized accesses, an empty `value` property is returned. When I test the same endpoints with a [Reader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#reader) role, the `value` property is populated.

Comment: file a bug report? not sure how we can help here?

Comment: Which rest api did you use?

Comment: @JoyWang I've tested this on several endpoints, including this, for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/logprofiles/list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer I received from Microsoft on the subject:

> The behavior you are seeing is expected for APIs that return a
>   collection of resources, the reason for this is that the permissions
>   are evaluated per resource, so that only the resources where you have
>   permissions are returned.
>
> This is the way we process the request:
>
> 1. We verify the permissions of the user making the call, if there are no permissions, an Unauthorized error is returned.
> 2. The API call is then sent to the resource provider to handle, in this case, we ask for the full collection of resources.
> 3. The results returned from the resource providers are then filtered based on the permissions the user has.
> 4. The filtered results are returned to the user. (If everything was filtered out, then the response will be empty).
>
> I understand how this may be confusing, in this case, the list API is
>   not restricted for the user, we restrict the results returned in the
>   response, that's why a 200 OK with an empty array is the correct
>   response to the scenario you have shared with us.